# Understanding the List Operator (%) in Boost.Spirit

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

Can you help me understand the difference between the `a % b` parser and its expanded `a >> *(b >> a)` form in Boost.Spirit? Even though [the reference manual](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/list.html) states that they are equivalent,

> The list operator, `a % b`, is a binary operator that matches a list of one or more repetitions of `a` separated by occurrences of `b`. This is equivalent to `a >> *(b >> a)`.

the following program produces different results depending on which is used:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

struct Record {
  int id;
  std::vector<int> values;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Record,
  (int, id)
  (std::vector<int>, values)
)

int main() {
  namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

  const auto str = std::string{"1: 2, 3, 4"};

  const auto rule1 = qi::int_ >> ':' >> (qi::int_ % ',')                 >> qi::eoi;
  const auto rule2 = qi::int_ >> ':' >> (qi::int_ >> *(',' >> qi::int_)) >> qi::eoi;

  Record record1;
  if (qi::phrase_parse(str.begin(), str.end(), rule1, qi::space, record1)) {
    std::cout << record1.id << ": ";
    for (const auto& value : record1.values) { std::cout << value << ", "; }
    std::cout << '\n';
  } else {
    std::cerr << "syntax error\n";
  }

  Record record2;
  if (qi::phrase_parse(str.begin(), str.end(), rule2, qi::space, record2)) {
    std::cout << record2.id << ": ";
    for (const auto& value : record2.values) { std::cout << value << ", "; }
    std::cout << '\n';
  } else {
    std::cerr << "syntax error\n";
  }
}
```

[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f11b90c4dc24d85f)

```
1: 2, 3, 4, 
1: 2,
```

`rule1` and `rule2` are different only in that `rule1` uses the list operator (`(qi::int_ % ',')`) and `rule2` uses its expanded form (`(qi::int_ >> *(',' >> qi::int_))`). However, `rule1` produced `1: 2, 3, 4,` (as expected) and  `rule2` produced `1: 2,`. I cannot understand the result of `rule2`: 1) why is it different from that of `rule1` and 2) why were `3` and `4` not included in `record2.values` even though `phrase_parse` returned true somehow?

Comment: Someone who has the pleasure of remembering the Spirit terminology can explain it better, but they look equivalent in what they match, but not in the type they accept for storing the values. The second appears to work with `(int, int, vector<int>)` rather than `(int, vector<int>)`. I'm guessing `vector<int>` is compatible with a single `int_` and then the repeated `int_`s (within the `*(…)`) are ignored when storing values.

Comment: Yup that's it, see my answer @chris. There's a _big_ error in the code though, so there's that (anything could have happened)

Comment: @sehe, Thanks, I'm interested in Spirit, but I haven't had a chance to use it for something yet. The CppCon X3 talk was pretty cool.

Comment: @chris That triggered me to do the corresponding test cases in Spirit X3. As expected, the situation is a whole lot better on the whole (no UB, no silent attribute propagation failures, not to mention vastly improved compile times :)). See my [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33817135/85371)

Comment: Another difference is that if `b` has an attribute (not the case in your example), it is ignored in `a%b` but not in `a >>*(b >> a)`. `a >> *(omit[b] >> a)` would be closer (but with the same problems shown in sehe's answer).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> **Update** X3 version [added](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33817135/85371)

First off, you fallen into a deep trap here:

Qi rules don't work with `auto`. Use `qi::copy` or just used `qi::rule<>`. Your program has undefined behaviour and indeed it crashed for me (valgrind pointed out where the dangling references originated).

So, first off:

```
const auto rule = qi::copy(qi::int_ >> ':' >> (qi::int_ % ',')                 >> qi::eoi);
```

Now, when you delete the redundancy in the program, you get:

### Reproducing the problem

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5cada4939db63b12)</kbd>**

```
int main() {
    test(qi::copy(qi::int_ >> ':' >> (qi::int_ % ',')));
    test(qi::copy(qi::int_ >> ':' >> (qi::int_ >> *(',' >> qi::int_))));
}
```

Printing

```
1: 2, 3, 4, 
1: 2,
```

### The cause and the fix

What happened to `3, 4` which was **successfully parsed**?

Well, the attribute propagation rules indicate that `qi::int_ >> *(',' >> qi::int_)` exposes a `tuple<int, vector<int> >`. In a bid to magically DoTheRightThing(TM) Spirit accidentally misfires and "assigngs" the `int` into the attribute reference, ignoring the remaining `vector<int>`.

If you want to make container attributes parse as "an atomic group", use `qi::as<>`:

```
test(qi::copy(qi::int_ >> ':' >> qi::as<Record::values_t>() [ qi::int_ >> *(',' >> qi::int_)]));
```

Here `as<>` acts as a barrier for the attribute compatibility heuristics and the grammar knows what you meant:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8db6c5bef6e4b548)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

struct Record {
  int id;
  using values_t = std::vector<int>;
  values_t values;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Record, id, values)

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

template <typename T>
void test(T const& rule) {
    const std::string str = "1: 2, 3, 4";

    Record record;

    if (qi::phrase_parse(str.begin(), str.end(), rule >> qi::eoi, qi::space, record)) {
        std::cout << record.id << ": ";
        for (const auto& value : record.values) { std::cout << value << ", "; }
        std::cout << '\n';
    } else {
        std::cerr << "syntax error\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    test(qi::copy(qi::int_ >> ':' >> (qi::int_ % ',')));
    test(qi::copy(qi::int_ >> ':' >> (qi::int_ >> *(',' >> qi::int_))));
    test(qi::copy(qi::int_ >> ':' >> qi::as<Record::values_t>() [ qi::int_ >> *(',' >> qi::int_)]));
}
```

Prints

```
1: 2, 3, 4, 
1: 2, 
1: 2, 3, 4,
```

Comment: Does it mean that, when Qi tried to match `tuple<int, vector<int>> = {2, {3, 4}}` with `vector<int> = Record::values`, Qi happened to convert `tuple<int, vector<int>> = {2, {3, 4}}` into `vector<int> = {2}`, not the expected `vector<int> = {2, 3, 4}`, due to some implementation details?

Comment: And how can `qi::as<>` rectify the problem? According to [the manual](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/directive/as.html), `qi::as<>` is about commit/rollback semantics. So, when parsing is successful,  shouldn't the parser produce the same result regardless of the existence of `qi::as<>`?

Comment: @user5583413 `qi::hold` is about commit/rollback semantics. As the docs for [`as<>[]`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/directive/as.html) indicate: _"**Note**
The `as<T>` implicitly causes commit/rollback semantics similar in nature to the hold directive."_ but that's it. It's really an annotation to tell the parser how you would like your container attribute synthesized. And _that_ is made "atomically" there. (The wording is a bit confusing.)

Comment: So can I understand it this way?  --- [The compound attribute rule (`a: A, b: vector<A> --> (a >> b): vector<A>`)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/quick_reference/compound_attribute_rules.html) does not always apply. The exact condition on when it does not apply is not specified (at least not documented) or too complicated to describe. Fortunately we can always enforce it by `qi::as<vector<A>>` or `x3::rule<..., vector<A>>`.

Comment: (Continuing the previous comment) For `tuple<A, vector<A>>`, Qi has been accidentally written so that a parser stores only the first element of the tuple into its supplied container attribute of type `vector<A>`, ignoring the second element of the tuple (`vector<A>`). X3 rigorously rejects it at compile-time.

Comment: Basically yes. I'd try to be a whole lot less confusing in the description, but I guess  my answer was for that already. I wouldn't trust "rigorously" - there are always heuristics involved in a framework that does automatic, generic, extensible attribute transformations. But yeah, it's more rigid and controlled than in the old days.

Comment: Thanks! I feel that I understand it now.

Comment: @user5583413 It's not exactly the same cases but you can see an attempt  at an explanation of similar problems [here](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Unexpected-behavior-using-versus-tp4662087p4662134.html) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16001652/2417774).

Answer (score 10):

Because it's time to get people started with X3 (the new version of Spirit), and because I like to challenge msyelf to do the corresponding tasks in Spirit X3, here is the Spirit X3 version.

There's no problem with `auto` in X3.

The "broken" case also behaves much better, triggering this static assertion:

```
    // If you got an error here, then you are trying to pass
    // a fusion sequence with the wrong number of elements
    // as that expected by the (sequence) parser.
    static_assert(
        fusion::result_of::size<Attribute>::value == (l_size + r_size)
      , "Attribute does not have the expected size."
    );
```

That's **nice**, right?

The workaround seems a bit less readable:

```
test(int_ >> ':' >> (rule<struct _, Record::values_t>{} = (int_ >> *(',' >> int_))));
```

But it would be trivial to write your own `as<>` "directive" (or just a function), if you wanted:

```
namespace {
    template <typename T>
    struct as_type {
        template <typename Expr>
            auto operator[](Expr&& expr) const {
                return x3::rule<struct _, T>{"as"} = x3::as_parser(std::forward<Expr>(expr));
            }
    };

    template <typename T> static const as_type<T> as = {};
}
```

### DEMO

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6ea786d6c09623dc)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

struct Record {
    int id;
    using values_t = std::vector<int>;
    values_t values;
};

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

template <typename T>
void test(T const& rule) {
    const std::string str = "1: 2, 3, 4";

    Record record;

    auto attr = std::tie(record.id, record.values);

    if (x3::phrase_parse(str.begin(), str.end(), rule >> x3::eoi, x3::space, attr)) {
        std::cout << record.id << ": ";
        for (const auto& value : record.values) { std::cout << value << ", "; }
        std::cout << '\n';
    } else {
        std::cerr << "syntax error\n";
    }
}

namespace {
    template <typename T>
    struct as_type {
        template <typename Expr>
            auto operator[](Expr&& expr) const {
                return x3::rule<struct _, T>{"as"} = x3::as_parser(std::forward<Expr>(expr));
            }
    };

    template <typename T> static const as_type<T> as = {};
}

int main() {
    using namespace x3;
    test(int_ >> ':' >> (int_ % ','));
    //test(int_ >> ':' >> (int_ >> *(',' >> int_))); // COMPILER asserts "Attribute does not have the expected size."

    // "clumsy" x3 style workaround
    test(int_ >> ':' >> (rule<struct _, Record::values_t>{} = (int_ >> *(',' >> int_))));

    // using an ad-hoc `as<>` implementation:
    test(int_ >> ':' >> as<Record::values_t>[int_ >> *(',' >> int_)]);
}
```

Prints

```
1: 2, 3, 4, 
1: 2, 3, 4, 
1: 2, 3, 4,
```