# BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE not understand

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, boost, boost-spirit-x3

I'm trying to write an expression parser with boost spirit x3.
I based my new code on old code that I written years ago (and worked well) with Spirit 2.x (qi).

The core of my code is:

```
   //Make new rule(s) for expression
    auto term = factor >> *(('*' >> factor) | ('/' >> factor));
    auto expression = term >> *(('+' >> term) | ('-' >> term));
    auto group = '(' >> expression >> ')';
    auto factor = lexeme["double_"] | group;

     
    string s="12.4 + 3.2";

    auto first = s.begin();
    auto last = s.end();
    bool r = x3::phrase_parse(
        first,
        last,
        //  Begin grammar
        expression,
        //  End grammar
        x3::space);
```

I obtain two errors (Visual Studio 2019):
Error   C2338   BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE undefined for this rule.
Error   C2039   'parse': is not a member of 'boost::spirit::x3::unused_type'

Why?

Answer (score 2):

BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE is used to associate a static rule-tag with a *definition* (i.e. an instantiation of the parse function template for that rule).

The good news is that this is frequently unnecessary, and rules can be defined in-line without any macros.

In general, the following reasons exist to use `x3::rule`:

1. When rules use recursion. The rule(s) that are invoked recursively need to have the undefined rule (uninitialized `rule<>` object) to refer to (much like a forward declaration).
2. To coerce the exposed attribute type (in my exeperience the need for this is a bit more common in X3 than it was in Qi: [Understanding the List Operator (%) in Boost.Spirit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33816662/understanding-the-list-operator-in-boost-spirit/33817135#33817135), or e.g. [boost::spirit::x3 attribute compatibility rules, intuition or code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37201023/boostspiritx3-attribute-compatibility-rules-intuition-or-code?noredirect=1&lq=1)).
3. When you want to spread your rule definitions across translation units (i.e. have external definitions). Note this also requires you to know the context and iterator type(s) you need to support so you can instantiate appropriately.
4. To benefit from the builtin rule debugging (`#define BOOST_SPIRIT_X3_DEBUG`). *This is the only reason I know off to use the `BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE` family of macros*

   > This frequently gives rise to hard-to diagnose linker errors so I recommend against this in most cases: X3 parsers compile fast enough in practice that I can afford to keep them in a single translation unit

---

### Your Sample

Only `expression` is used recursively. For the rest it suffices to simply reorder them:

```
namespace parser {
    x3::rule<struct expression_> expression{"expression"};
   
    auto group          = '(' >> expression >> ')';
    auto factor         = x3::lexeme["double_"] | group;
    auto term           = factor >> *(('*' >> factor) | ('/' >> factor));
    auto expression_def = term >> *(('+' >> term) | ('-' >> term));

    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(expression)
}
```

See it **[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/PsrMd7)** printing:

```
<expression>
  <try>12.4 + 3.2</try>
  <fail/>
</expression>
------ 12.4 + 3.2
r: false
remaining input: '12.4 + 3.2'
```

It is clear that your `factor` rule should be back to normal:

```
auto factor         = x3::double_ | group;
```

See it **[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/nf1rjn)** printing:

```
<expression>
  <try>12.4 + 3.2</try>
  <success></success>
</expression>
------ 12.4 + 3.2
r: true
remaining input: ''
```

### BONUS: Attributes

Adding attribute propagation will highlight what I meant under 2. above:

```
namespace Ast {
    struct binop;

    using expression = boost::make_recursive_variant<
        double,
        boost::recursive_wrapper<binop>,
        boost::recursive_variant_
    >::type;

    struct binop {
        char op;
        expression lhs, rhs;
    };
}
```

That's the simplest thing that could work. Your rules are pretty efficient for constructing the ast from semantic actions¹:

```
namespace parser {
    x3::rule<struct expression_, Ast::expression> expression{"expression"};

    auto assign = [](auto& ctx) { _val(ctx) = _attr(ctx); };
    auto make_binop = [](auto& ctx) {
        using boost::fusion::at_c;
        auto& op = at_c<0>(_attr(ctx));
        auto& rhs = at_c<1>(_attr(ctx));
        _val(ctx) = Ast::binop { op, _val(ctx), rhs };
    };
   
    auto group   
        = x3::rule<struct group_, Ast::expression> {"group"}
        = '(' >> expression >> ')';

    auto factor
        = x3::rule<struct factor_, Ast::expression> {"factor"}
        = x3::double_ | group;

    auto term
        = x3::rule<struct term_, Ast::expression> {"term"}
        = factor [assign] >> *(x3::char_("*/") >> factor) [make_binop];

    auto expression_def
        = term [assign] >> *(x3::char_("-+") >> term) [make_binop];

    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(expression)
}
```

See it **[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/E4nM6c)**:

```
int main() {
    for (std::string const s : {
            "12.4 + 3.2",
        })
    {
        auto f = s.begin(), l = s.end();
        Ast::expression e;
        bool r = x3::phrase_parse(f, l, parser::expression, x3::space, e);

        std::cout
            << "------ " << s << "\n"
            << "r: " << std::boolalpha << r << "\n";

        if (r)
            std::cout << "e: " << e << "\n";

        if (f!=l)
            std::cout << "remaining input: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
    }
}
```

Printing

```
------ 12.4 + 3.2
r: true
e: (12.4 + 3.2)
```

And the debug output:

```
<expression>
  <try>12.4 + 3.2</try>
  <term>
    <try>12.4 + 3.2</try>
    <factor>
      <try>12.4 + 3.2</try>
      <success> + 3.2</success>
      <attributes>12.4</attributes>
    </factor>
    <success> + 3.2</success>
    <attributes>12.4</attributes>
  </term>
  <term>
    <try> 3.2</try>
    <factor>
      <try> 3.2</try>
      <success></success>
      <attributes>3.2</attributes>
    </factor>
    <success></success>
    <attributes>3.2</attributes>
  </term>
  <success></success>
  <attributes>(12.4 + 3.2)</attributes>
</expression>
```

---

¹ Here I don't mention [my usual screed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil) because using automatic propagation *in this kind of grammar* tends to lead to a lot of backtracking in the grammar, which makes it inefficient

Comment: Added a demo with attribute propagation **[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/E4nM6c)**

Comment: Can you elaborate how to achieve point 3 ?  I am stuck with helpless information : 
third_party/boost/boost/spirit/home/x3/nonterminal/rule.hpp, line 33, column 23: error: static assertion failed: BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE undefined for this rule.
         static_assert(!is_same<decltype(get<ID>(context)), unused_type>::value,

Comment: @sandwood I can. I prefer not to. The official library examples show how to use ..._DECLARE, ..._DEFINE and ..._INSTANTIATE, e.g. I can help you out as well if you post a self-contained example. Or you can search my answers because I've helped others in the past: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A85371+BOOST_SPIRIT_INSTANTIATE (The reason I prefer not to is because I think X3 stops being practical when you feel the need to spread over TUs.  Actually, I baulk at using the macros at all)

Comment: I see. I would 100% agree. Unfortunately in my case  the issue is that mainly compilation time of the single TU stars to rocket above 3min so it's an issue, and I still have a lot to add in the parser...

Comment: @sandwood Usually I draw one of two conclusions: (1) you need to contain everything Spirit related in 1 TU, not leaking *anything* in the header (2) you need to rethink the approach. For me, it is never an issue to have a single slow TU if it rarely changes. That said, there are ways to optimize compilation. I might have a look, if you post a question :)