# How do you get a string out of a Boost Spirit X3 lexeme parser?

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

What is the simplest way to make a semantic action that extracts a string from a typical identifier parser based on `boost::spirit::x3::lexeme`?

I thought it might be possible to bypass needing to unpack the attribute and just use iterators into the input stream but apparently `x3::_where` does not do what I think it does.

The following yields `output` being empty. I expected it to contain "foobar_hello".

```
namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

using x3::_where;
using x3::lexeme;
using x3::alpha;

auto ctx_to_string = [&](auto& ctx) {
    _val(ctx) = std::string(_where(ctx).begin(), _where(ctx).end());
};

x3::rule<class identifier_rule_, std::string> const identifier_rule = "identifier_rule";
auto const identifier_rule_def = lexeme[(x3::alpha | '_') >> *(x3::alnum | '_')][ctx_to_string];
BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(identifier_rule);

int main()
{
    std::string input = "foobar_hello";

    std::string output;
    auto result = x3::parse(input.begin(), input.end(), identifier_rule, output);
}
```

Do I need to somehow extract the string from the boost::fusion objects in `x3::_attr(ctx)` or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use automatic attribute propagation, meaning you don't need the semantic action(1)

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6cfbda669585cc24)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_X3_DEBUG
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

namespace P {
    x3::rule<class identifier_rule_, std::string> const identifier_rule = "identifier_rule";
    auto const identifier_rule_def = x3::lexeme[(x3::alpha | x3::char_('_')) >> *(x3::alnum | x3::char_('_'))];
    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(identifier_rule)
}

int main() {
    std::string const input = "foobar_hello";

    std::string output;
    auto result = x3::parse(input.begin(), input.end(), P::identifier_rule, output);
}
```

Prints

```
<identifier_rule>
  <try>foobar_hello</try>
  <success></success>
  <attributes>[f, o, o, b, a, r, _, h, e, l, l, o]</attributes>
</identifier_rule>
```

> Note I changed `'_'` to `x3::char_('_')` to capture the underscores (`x3::lit` does not capture what it matches)

If you insist on semantic actions,

- consider using `rule<..., std::string, true>` to *also* force automatic attrobute propagation
- don't assume `_where` points to what you hope: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/336c057dabc86a84
- use `x3::raw[]` to expose a controlled source iterator range (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/80a69ae9b99a4c61)

  ```
  auto ctx_to_string = [](auto& ctx) {
      std::cout << "\nSA: '" << _attr(ctx) << "'" << std::endl;
      _val(ctx) = std::string(_attr(ctx).begin(), _attr(ctx).end());
  };

  x3::rule<class identifier_rule_, std::string> const identifier_rule = "identifier_rule";
  auto const identifier_rule_def = x3::raw[ lexeme[(x3::alpha | '_') >> *(x3::alnum | '_')] ] [ctx_to_string];
  BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(identifier_rule)
  ```

  > Note now the `char_('_')` doesn't make a difference anymore
- consider using the built-in attribute helpers: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e3861330494e7c9

  ```
  auto ctx_to_string = [](auto& ctx) {
      using x3::traits::move_to;
      move_to(_attr(ctx), _val(ctx));
  };
  ```

  Note how this approximates the builtin attribute propagation, though it's much less flexible than letting Spirit manage it

(1) mandatory link: [Boost Spirit: "Semantic actions are evil"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil)

Comment: Seems like semantic actions are necessary if your output structures do not use value type-based composition though. My problem now is that this was the SO minimal reproducible version of my problem. Why I need a semantic action is that I want to dynamically allocate an object of class T using the string and have a shared_ptr<T> be the attribute of the rule. I can do this using attribute propagation via two rules and one semantic action but it seems verbose. Is there a way to get spirit to collapse attributes into a given type before the semantic action is called?

Comment: About shared_ptr and the like: see [same caveats as for Qi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37912787/85371). I think you need the "two-rule approach" to get attribute _coercion_. You can "cheat" and use this trick with `as<>` or you know, a `make_shared<>` along the similar lines as here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43093437/85371

Comment: thanks your as<> template allows me to remove several helper rules actually. the authors of X3 are philosophically opposed to adding it to Spirit, I take it?